# Unable to do animation while calling the previous activity in android

Tags: android

I have two activities. Activity 1 and activity 2. I have given animation when I call activity 2 from activity 1.

The kind of animation that I have given is that activity 1 should move to right side and activity 2 should come from left side to right side and take the position of activity 1 (->activity2->activity1->). I am successfully able to do that. I am finishing activity 1 as soon as I call activity 2.

Now I am trying to call activity 1 from activity 2. I want activity 2 to move to left side and activity 1 should come from right side to left side and take the position of activity 2 (<-activity 2<-activity 1<-). I am finishing activity 2 when I call activity 1. The problem is that, when I try to do that the activity 1 appears two times.

The problem is like this, as soon as I press on the button for calling activity 1 from activity 2, activity 1 appears suddenly without any animation. Then activity 1 slides away and activity 1 comes again.

Here is the xml code I use for moving from activity 1 to activity 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Here is the xml code I use for moving from activity 2 to activity 1:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

   <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>

</set>
```

Here is the code for moving from activity 1 to activity 2:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setClassName(Generator.this,"com.xyz.activity2");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.left_to_right);
```

Here is the code for moving from activity 2 to activity 1:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setClassName(MainMenu.this,"com.xyz.activity1");
                    startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.right_to_left);
```

Comment: I think there is something to do with your pendingTransition. It should have twot parameters(enterAnimation and exitAnimation). you have defined same animation for both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this....

in A Activity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(A_Acitivity.this,B_Activity.class);
startActivityForResult(i,100);
```

and this is OnActivityResult Method...

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.right_to_left);

    }
```

onCreate() of B Activity.java

```
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.left_to_right);
```

on back button of B Activity

just call finish();

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code. and made a little edit to it. Just call the `finish()` function before calling the new intent.

```
        finish();
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setClassName(Generator.this,"com.xyz.activity2");
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.left_to_right);
```

This is now working fine in my device. Let me know if it worked for you or not.